# How do you use a T-SQL variable within an if OBJECT_ID to check if a table exists?

Tags: sql-server, exists

What I am trying to do with the following code is have it grab all the database names then loop through those databases check to see if the table `tblAdminLogin` exists and if it does update the password for username 'foo'

I have been using a select statement instead of an update as of yet until it works properly.

```
declare @databases table
(
    PK      int IDENTITY(1,1), 
    dbid    int,
    name    varchar(50)
)

insert into @databases(dbid, name) select dbid, name from master.dbo.sysdatabases

Declare @maxPK int; select @maxPK = MAX(PK) from @databases
Declare @pk int; Set @pk = 1
Declare @name varchar(50)

While @pk <= @maxPK
Begin
    Select @name = name from @databases where PK=@pk
    if OBJECT_ID(''+@name+'.dbo.tblAdminLogin') IS NOT NULL
    Begin
        Select password from @name.dbo.tblAdminLogin where username = 'foo'
        --Update @name.dbo.tblAdminLogin Set password='bar' where username = 'foo' 
    End
    Set @pk = @pk + 1
End
```

The main code in question is

```
    Select @name = name from @databases where PK=@pk
    if OBJECT_ID(''+@name+'.dbo.tblAdminLogin') IS NOT NULL
    Begin
        Select password from @name.dbo.tblAdminLogin where username = 'foo'
        --Update @name.dbo.tblAdminLogin Set password='bar' where username = 'foo' 
    End
```

Edit: Added T-SQL to title since I am using SQL Server

Edit: Fixed the Typo .dbl. to the correct .dbo.

Comment: I know you selected an answer, but the best way to do this is clearly using `sp_msforeachdb`.  When the api provides a way, it is always a good idea to use it.  Check out the answer which show how to use `sp_msforeachdb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic SQL.

Untested

```
declare @SQL varchar(max) -- varchar(8000) if on SQL Server 2000 or earlier
While @pk <= @maxPK  
Begin      
    Select @name = name from @databases where PK=@pk
    if OBJECT_ID(''+@name+'.dbo.tblAdminLogin') IS NOT NULL      
    Begin          
        set @SQL = 'update ' + quotename(@name) + '.dbo.tblAdminLogin Set     password=''bar'' where username = ''foo'''
        exec (@SQL)
    End
    set @PK = @PK + 1
End
```

References:

- [QUOTENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx)
- [EXECUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

Edit: general note on types, not asked for by OP:

The database name is of type SYSNAME which, last I checked, is equivelent to a NVARCHAR(128). Storing that value in a VARCHAR type has the chance of losing information. Small chance at some site because of the names they would choose, but a chance none the less.

```
declare @databases table
(
    PK      int IDENTITY(1,1), 
    dbid    int,
    name    sysname
)

insert into @databases(dbid, name) select dbid, name from master.dbo.sysdatabases

Declare @maxPK int; select @maxPK = MAX(PK) from @databases
Declare @pk int; Set @pk = 1
Declare @name sysname -- so that 

declare @SQL nvarchar(4000) 
While @pk <= @maxPK  

Begin      
    Select @name = name from @databases where PK=@pk
    if OBJECT_ID(@name+N'.dbo.tblAdminLogin') IS NOT NULL      
    Begin          
        set @SQL = N'update ' + quotename(@name) + N'.dbo.tblAdminLogin Set     password=''bar'' where username = ''foo'''
        exec (@SQL)
    End
    set @PK = @PK + 1
End
```

Comment: Are you certain you have a <dbname>.dbl.tblAdminLogin in one or more databases? I don't have SQL Server handy, looks like it should work, so I'm stymied on why the call to object_id is not working.

Comment: @Shannon I fixed my typo .dbl. to .dbo. and the OBJECT_ID Portion Worked but the set @SQL portion returns the error "The name 'update [dbname].dbo.tblAdminLogin Set password='bar' where username='foo' ' is not a valid identifier."

Comment: @Shannon  Yes it is in 40 or so databases.  By the way thanks for the tip on sysname

Comment: @Dave M: Needs parens around @SQL on the exec line: `exec (@SQL)`. Will update answer.

Comment: I used to always use `exec sp_executesql @SQL` but could not remember the reason why. Maybe it is silliness around needing the parens to execute string versus looking for a stored procedure named by the string.

Comment: @Shannon :)  Thanks that was the ticket!

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 
  'Use [?]; if object_id(''tblAdminLogin'') is not null Select password from tblAdminLogin where username = ''foo'''
```

Answer (score 1):

I might do something like this:

```
exec sp_msforeachdb '
if (object_id(''[?].[dbo].[tblAdminLogin]'', ''U'')) is not null
begin
  update table [?].[dbo].[tblAdminLogin] Set password=''bar'' where username = ''foo''
  select ''?'', username, password from [?].[dbo].[tblAdminLogin] where username = ''foo''
end
'
```